# How do I navigate the external storage file system in Android 12?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-external-storage, file-manager, scoped-storage

I would like to make a file manager app targeting API level 31 that requires access to all files on the device. To do this, I have followed the guidance here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files.

I have added the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and allowed it in the device settings. Here is the Kotlin code I'm using to list the root directories on the device:

```
val file = Environment.getStorageDirectory()

// ensure we have file access permission
if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager() && Environment.isExternalStorageManager(file)) {
    Log.d("FileManager", "Exists: ${file.exists()}")
    Log.d("FileManager", "Is directory: ${file.isDirectory}")
    Log.d("FileManager", "List files: ${file.listFiles()}")
}
```

Here is the output:

```
D/FileManager: Exists: true
D/FileManager: Is directory: true
D/FileManager: List files: null
```

As you can see, the directory exists, but `listFiles()` unexpectedly returns `null`. Given this, how can I navigate all the files on the device, starting from the root directory?

I have seen similar questions, but their answers all seem outdated or unusable. Here are some of the suggestions I've found:

- Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

  - This works, but is deprecated in API level 31.
- Use `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

  - This is outdated.
- Use `ActivityResultContracts`

  - This does not apply to a custom file manager app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Given this, how can I navigate all the files on the device, starting from the root directory?

You can't, at least on unrooted devices. Even with `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, all that you have access to is external storage, not the entire device filesystem.

> Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` — This works, but is deprecated in API level 31.

[It is now undeprecated](https://commonsware.com/blog/2021/11/06/about-environment-undeprecations.html), as of Android 12L and Android 13 DP2. Hopefully the public documentation will reflect this when Android 13 ships later this year.

> Use android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" — This is outdated.

You still want it for Android 10 support.

Comment: Thanks so much, I had no idea it was undeprecated. One small thing: I noticed I still get `null` for the app-specific files in the "data" directory of the external storage. However, I have a 3rd party app on my phone called "Cx File Explorer" that lets me access these files. Do you know how I could list these files in my own app?

Comment: Actually, looking into it further, it seems like that app and many other file manager apps switch to the Storage Access Framework for that folder in particular. Inconvenient, but it works well enough. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a uses permission `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to manifest file is not enough to get 'all files access'.

You also at runtime have to start an intent for `Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION`.